# Scraping the total time uploaded to a Youtube channel with BeautifulSoup or selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the individual video lengths for all videos on one channel and store it in a list or something.

So first I tried Beautiful Soup by using requests library and doing findAll("div") but I get nothing useful. None of the elements look at all like the inspect element on the youtube channel page. Apparently it's because YouTube loads dynamically or something. So you have to use selenium. Idk what that means, but anyway I tried selenium and got this error:

Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="video-title"]"}

from this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = (path\chromedriver.exe)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(r"https://www.youtube.com/c/0214mex/videos?view=0&sort=dd&shelf_id=0")
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element(By.ID,"video-title")

print(search)

driver.quit()
```

I get the feeling I don't really understand how web scraping works. Usually if I wanted to grab elements from a webpage I'd just do the soup thing, findAll on div and then keep going down until I reached the a tag or whatever I needed. But I'm having no luck with doing that on YT channel pages.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I can clearly see the hierarchy when I do inspect element on the YouTube page. It goes:
body -> div id=content -> ytd-browse class... -> ytd-two-column-browse-results... -> div id=primary -> div id=contents -> div id =items -> div id = dismissible -> div id =details -> div id=meta -> h3 class... -> and inside an a tag there's all the information I need.

I'm probably naive for thinking that if I simply findAll on "div" it would just show me all the divs, I'd then go to the last one div id=meta and then searchAll "h3" and then search "a" tags and I'd have my info. But searching for "div" with findAll (in BeautifulSoup) has none of those divs and actually the ones it comes up with I can't even find in the select element thing.

So yeah, I seem to be misunderstanding how the findAll thing works. Can anyone provide a simple step-by-step way of getting the information which I'm looking for? Is it impossible without using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

### Problem explanation

YouTube is dynamic in nature what it means is, basically the more you load by doing scroll down, the more content it will show. So yes that's dynamic in nature.

So even Selenium understand the same thing, scroll down and add more items title into the list. Also they are typical take few seconds to load, so having an explicit waits will definitely help you get all the title.

You need to maximize the windows, put `time.sleep(.5)` for visibility and bit of stability. I have put range to 200, meaning grab 200 title, you can put any sensible arbitrary number and script should do the magic.

Also, since it is dynamic, I have defined `number_of_title_to_scrape = 100`, you can try with your desired number as well.

### Solution

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/c/0214mex/videos")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
video_title = []
len_of_videos= len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='video-title']"))
j = 0
number_of_title_to_scrape = 100
for i in range(number_of_title_to_scrape):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='video-title']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elements[j])
    time.sleep(.5)
    title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of((elements[j])))
    print(title.text)
    video_title.append(title.text)
    j = j +1
    if j == number_of_title_to_scrape:
        break
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
【遊戯王】千年パズルが難易度最高レベルでマジで無理wwwww
【ルームツアー】3億円の豪邸の中ってどうなってるの？
コムドットと心霊スポット行ったらヤンキー達に道を塞がれた。
【事件】コムドットやまと。盗撮した人が変装したはじめしゃちょーでもキレ過ぎて分からない説wwwww
はじめしゃちょーで曲を作ってみた【2021年ver.】
3億円の豪邸を買いました！
【コアラのマーチ】新種のコアラ考えたら商品化されてしまいましたwwwww
ヨギボー100万円分買って部屋に全部置いてみた結果wwwww
自販機からコーラが止まらなくなりました
絶対にむせる焼きそばがあるらしいぞ！んなわけねえよ！
はじめしゃちょーがsumika「Lovers」歌ってみた【THE FIRST TAKE】
Mr.マリックのマジックを全部失敗させたら空気が...
ビビりの後輩を永遠にビックリさせてみたwwwwwwww
【泣くなはじめ】大家さん。今まで6年間ありがとうございました。
液体窒素を口の中に入れてみたwwwwww
ヒカルに1億円の掴み取りさせたら大変な事になってしまった。
ヒカルさんに縁切られました。電話してみます。
玄関に透明なアクリル板があったらぶつかる説
なんとかしてください。
【+1 FES 3rd STAGE】誰が最強？YouTuber瓦割り対決！
【実況付き】アナウンサーとニュースっぽく心霊スポット行ったら怖くない説wwwww
体重が軽過ぎる男がシーソーに乗った結果wwwww
糸電話を10年間待ち続けた結果…
愛車を人にあげる事になったので最後に改造しました。
【閲覧注意】ゴギブリを退治したいのに勢いだけで結局何もできないヤツ
【12Kg】巨大なアルミ玉の断面ってどうなってるの？切断します。
打つのに10年間かかる超スローボールを投げた結果…
人の家の前にジンオウガがいた結果wwwwwwww
【野球】高く打ち上げたボールを10年間待った結果…
シャンプー泡立ったままでイルカショー見に行ってみたwwwwwww
水に10年間潜り続けた男
ランニングマシン10年間走り続けた結果…
コロナ流行ってるけど親友の結婚式行ってきた。
10年間タピオカ吸い続けた結果...
【バスケ】スリーポイント10000回練習したぞ。
かくれんぼ10年間放置した結果...
【危険】24時間エスカレーター生活してみた。
1日ヒカキンさんの執事として働いてみたwwwww
人が食ってたパスタを液体窒素でカチカチにしといたwwwwwwwwww
1人だけ乗ってる観覧車が檻になってるドッキリwwwwwww
【検証】コカ･コーラが1番美味しいのはどんなシチュエーション？
はじめしゃちょーをアニメ風に描いてもらった結果wwwww
コーラの容器がブツブツになった結果wwwww #shorts
絶対にケガする重い扉を倒してみた結果wwwwww
ショートケーキの缶売ってたwwwww #shorts
ガチの事故物件で1日生活してみたら何か起こるの？
【初公開】はじめしゃちょーの1日密着動画。
コーラに油を混ぜてメントス入れたらすごい事になる？！　#shorts
【拡散希望】河野大臣…コロナワクチンって本当に大丈夫なん…？
ヤバい服見つけたんだがwwwwwwwwww
ヒカキンさんにチャンネル登録者数抜かれました。
What if the classroom you were hiding in the locker was a women's changing room?
コーラがトゲトゲになった結果wwwwww #shorts
エヴァンゲリオンが家の前に立っていたら...？
夏の始まり。1人で豪華客船を貸し切ってみた。女と行きたかった。
【検証】大食いYouTuber VS オレと業務用調理器。どっちが早いの？
天気良いのにオレの家だけ雨降らせたらバレる?バレない？wwwww
3000円ガチャ発見！PS5当たるまで回したらヤバい金額にwwwwww
カラオケで入れた曲のラスサビ永遠ループドッキリwwwwwwww
【ラーメン】ペヤング超超超超超超大盛りペタマックスの新作出たwwwwwww食います
深夜に急に家に入ってくる配達員。
オレは社会不適合者なのか
巨大なクマさん買い過ぎちゃった！
GACKTさん。オレGACKTさんみたいになりたいっス。
100万円の世界最強のスピーカー買ったんやけど全てがヤバいwwwww
【奇妙】ヒカキンさんにしか見えない人が1日中めっちゃ倒れてたらどうする？
ヘリウムガス吸い過ぎたら一生声が戻らなくなるドッキリwwwwwwww
スマブラ世界最強の男 VS 何でもして良いはじめしゃちょー
山田孝之とはじめしゃちょーの質問コーナー！そして消えた200万円。
山田孝之さんにめちゃくちゃ怒られました。
ヒカキンじゃんけんで絶対チョキを出させる方法を発見wwwwwwww
6年ぶりに銅羅で起こされたら同じ反応するの？
バイト先の後輩だった女性と結婚しました。
フォーエイトはエイトフォーで捕まえられるの？
ジムが素敵な女の子だらけだったら限界超えてバーベルめっちゃ上がる説
同棲？
はじめしゃちょー。バイクを買う。
【実話】過去に女性化していた事を話します。
【近未来】自走するスーツケースを買いました。もう乗り物。
ジェットコースターのレールの上を歩いてみた。
バカな後輩ならパイの実がめっちゃ大きくなってても気づかねえよwwwwwwww
久しぶりに他人を怒鳴ったわ
【42万円】Amazonですごいモノが売ってたので買いました。そして人の家の前へ
ペヤングの最新作がヤバ過ぎて全部食べれませんでした。
人の家の前で日本刀を持ったクマさんがずっと待ってる動画
3Pシュートを10000回練習したらどれくらい上手くなるの？【〜5000回】
おい佐藤二朗。オレとやり合おうや。
ひとりぼっちの君へ。
これはオレのしたかった東京の生活じゃない。
巨大なクマのぬいぐるみを浮かせたい
バスケットボール100個で試合したらプロに勝てるんじゃね？
【閲覧注意】100デシベル以上でねるねるねるね作ったら日本1うるさい動画になったwwwwww
オレずっと筋トレ続けてたんスよ。
収録までさせて勝手にDr.STONEの世界にオレがいる話作ってみた
失禁マシーンってのがあるらしいぞwwwwwwwww
謎の部屋に閉じ込められました。おや？真ん中になにかあるぞ？
家に来てほしくないから看板作りました。
これが未来のサウナです。
【恐怖映像】オレの後輩がガチでクズすぎる
就活あるある【ゲストが豪華】
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I edit this code to grab what's in the aria-label instead? Since that's what contains the video length.

Comment: Instead of `print(title.text)` use `print(title.get_attribute('aria-label'))` should help you past this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific number of videos- go for `for` loop as mentioned in another answer. Below code will keep scrolling until manually close the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/c/0214mex/videos")
j=0
try:
    while True: # Infinite loop, to keep scrolling.
       videos = driver.find_elements_by_id("dismissible") # Find all the videos. Initially the length of videos will be 30, keeps increasing as we scroll down.
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", videos[j]) # Scroll to all videos, more videos will be loaded and list of videos will be updated everytime.
       video_name = videos[j].find_element_by_tag_name("h3").get_attribute("innerText") # videos[j] - Get the name of jth video indiviually
       video_length = videos[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='style-scope ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer']").text # videos[j] - Get the length of jth video indiviually.
       print("{}: {}-{}".format(j+1,video_name,video_length)) # To print in specific format.
       j+=1 # Increment j
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

driver.quit()
```

Output: (Manually closed the browser)

```
1: 【遊戯王】千年パズルが難易度最高レベルでマジで無理wwwww-12:26
2: 【ルームツアー】3億円の豪邸の中ってどうなってるの？-8:20
3: コムドットと心霊スポット行ったらヤンキー達に道を塞がれた。-18:08
...
294: これがwww世界1巨大なwww人をダメにするソファwwwwww-8:06
295: 皆さまにお願いがあります。-4:18
Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```